# plesk PHP on write text to txt file gives error

Tags: php, plesk

I my VPS 2012 R2 i have a plesk configured and a domain when iam trying to create and write a text in txt file that gives me error i tried all possible ways to fix it am not able to do

My PHP

```
  <?php
$myfile = fopen("E:\Log\newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file! " . var_export(error_get_last(), true));
$txt = "Mickey Mouse\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Minnie Mouse\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Error :

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(E:\Log
ewfile.txt) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/test.in\;C:\Windows\Temp\) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\test.in\httpdocs\Test.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  fopen(E:\Log
ewfile.txt): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\test.in\httpdocs\Test.php on line 2
```

Comment: the folder is in full permission still gives me same error

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

Beside of `open_basedir`, your PHP script executes under special system user which has permissions **only inside** of `C:/Inetpub/vhosts/test.in`

Also check this "Additional write/modify permissions" in "Hosting Settings":
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've got `open_basedir` turned on which limits where PHP is allowed to read and write files (to protect against potential attacks or bugs that could read or write any file on the filesystem). Either remove the setting or write to a file within the configured base dir.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: i there a way that i can add a new directory even in the allowed directory that is not working

Comment: You can't read or write outside of the `open_basedir` setting, that's the whole point of that setting :P You could perhaps add `E:/Logs` to your `open_basedir`.